# Do i have to run garbage collection or something?

Tags: android, animation

```
  import android.app.Activity;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GenieComesOut extends Activity 
{

ImageView genie;
AnimationDrawable genieout;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.genie_out);
        genie = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.genieout);

        genieout = (AnimationDrawable) genie.getDrawable();
        genie.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {genieout.start();}});
    }
```

I got the animations to start going, i can only fit 20 frames in one, more than that i get VM wont allocate, these are full screen images, i have about 50 frames left, so, can i make a new /anim/xml switch onto the ImageView garbage collect and runnable another 20 frames, what is the proper way to do this? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider converting your animation to a video if that is really fullscreen. Video can then be played easily and won't eat your memory.

Here is the list of supported formats: [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). You could use H264 or 3GP, try what looks best and performs better.

Comment: i thought that 24 straight researching hours ago, ill look into it, do it in a video editor then VideoView right?

Comment: what type should i output the video as when i make it?